# Initial Value Prob in Matlab

Tags: matlab, calculus

Suppose a symbolically defined f(t) satisfies the initial value problem f′(t) + 2 sin(t) = f(t) with f(pi) = 0. Use dsolve wrapped in subs to find f(0).

My answer is:

```
answer = subs( dsolve( diff(f,1)+2*sin(t) == f , f(pi) == 0), t, 0)
```

However, that gave me the wrong output, could anyone help explain?

Comment: What output do you get and what output do you expect? Please post a complete code example.

Comment: This gives me a 0 as an output, this is not the right answer however. I did the problem by hand and it is not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being defining issues. I had created 2 symbolic functions f(t) and f(x). Matlab had issues distinguishing between the 2.

A simple extra input argument was enough to tell Matlab which function I was referring too (the t variable one).

```
answer = subs( dsolve( diff(f,1)+2*sin(t) == f , f(pi) == 0, t), t, 0)
```